# Android: Tracing a multi-touch gesture

Tags: android, gesture

I'm attempting to create a simple Application that traces a user's gestures on the screen. Now with single touch gestures this can be achieved rather simply by using the following code in your `OnTouchEvent` method:

```
switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              path.reset();
              this.invalidate();
              path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
              path.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
              return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

              break;
            default:
              return false;
        }
```

[The `addcircle` method simply creates a circle signifying the where the user initially put their finger].

Now, is it possible to achieve this same effect with a multi-touch gesture? If so, how would I go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I eventually found a solution. It's not exactly what I wanted but it's the closest I've gotten so far. Essentially I keep a two dimensional `ArrayList` containing all the co-ordinates of the user's fingers (to a maximum of four fingers). Upon the user completing their gesture I then start another activity that runs through the 2D`ArrayList` and draws all the points onto the canvas. If anyone wants more detail to this solution just leave a comment and I can add some code and explain a little more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [Handling Multi-Touch Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) chapter in the documentation.

Essentially, every `MotionEvent` also has a pointer, which allows to track multiple fingers. You would have to do all state handling on your own.

In case you're trying to implement something common, take a look at [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) which supports flinging, tapping, double tapping and scrolling.